# Redirecting Domain name to IP address using custom port

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect the domain name to IP address with .htaccess file, i am able to do it successfully without using any custom port but i want this to redirect to custom port i.e. 52531. I am pasting my redirection code below.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteOptions inherit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^hardworkerz\.net$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.hardworkerz\.net$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/103\.7\.129\.132\/CorporateUI" [R=301,L]
```

Can anyone guide me how to do this with using custom port 52531.

Comment: it's just a url... `.... 129.132:52531/CorporateUI`

Comment: Also you don't need to escape the IP in the substitution string since you can't use regex there.